# Core Data object deleting error

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode7

I am testing my app with TestFlight - and i see two same crashes on different devices (iPhone 5S 8.3 and iPhone 6 9.2).

This crashes happened only one time on each device but i think that there is some problem. When i open "Open in project" - i don't see where exactly in my project this crash occurs. As i see - this happens when Core Data runs object delete method.

I use Core Data to store cache and each time i receive new data from server - i clear all core data entities one by one and then create new. This is my function to clear cache. (This code is used to have iOS 7 support)

```
func clearCache() {
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()
fetchRequest.entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("CacheItems", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)
fetchRequest.includesPropertyValues = false

do {
    let results = try managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [NSManagedObject]
    for result in results {
        managedObjectContext.deleteObject(result)
    }

} catch {
    let nserror = error as NSError
    NSLog("CoreData erasing error - \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
}

// checking Cache items count
do {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "CacheItems")
    myCacheItems = try managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [CacheItemsClass]
} catch let error as NSError {
    print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
} }
```

[image]

Comment: you should case following line like as an optional `let results = try managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [NSManagedObject]` to `let results = try managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as? [NSManagedObject]` 
and then check if results contains a reference.

Comment: What thread to you call your method on? What's your concurrency type?

Comment: @Afnan, if i just add "?" i get errors while building after it - can you show me full block of code?

Comment: Can you paste that error here?

Comment: @jcaron, i am very new to threads - so i run clearCache method inside let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request)
            { clearEventCache() .....  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{ /*in this block i get data from server*/} }

Comment: @Afnan, i added this "?" and "!" to results 
do {
        let results = try managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as? [NSManagedObject]
        for result in results! { if(result != nil) {
            managedObjectContext.deleteObject(result)
}
        }
        eventsCacheItems.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
    } 

and i get error that Value of type 'NSManagedObject' can never be nil, comparison isn't allowed

Comment: The callback of `dataTaskWithRequest` is called on a background thread. Depending on your concurrency type (i.e. how you initialise your `NSManagedObjectContext`), this may break Core Data access. Either move your call to `clearEventCache` inside the `dispatch_async` block, or read up on Core Data concurrency types and adjust your code accordingly.